# Nested select statements

Tags: stored-procedures

I am trying to return results based on the number of cases if greater than 0 but when i try to execute the stored procedure i get an error stating: Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is is incompatible with tinyint. And that is for my nested select statement in where clause.

```
SELECT 
      O.OfficeId,
      O.OfficeName AS Name,
      AT.Description AS CaseActivity,
      SUM(A.Duration) AS [CaseMinutes], 
      CAST(SUM(A.Duration) AS FLOAT) / 60 AS [CaseHours],  
      COUNT(A.ActivityId) AS Activities,
      COUNT(DISTINCT A.CaseId) AS Cases,
      MIN(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Case Min Time],
      MAX(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Case Max Time],
      SUM(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) / COUNT(A.ActivityId) AS [Case Avg Time],
      SUM(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Case TotalHours]
  FROM Activity A
      INNER JOIN ActivityType AT ON A.ActivityTypeId = AT.ActivityTypeId
      INNER JOIN ActivityEntry AE ON A.ActivityEntryId = AE.ActivityEntryId
      INNER JOIN [Case] C ON A.CaseId = C.CaseId
      INNER JOIN [Office] O ON AE.OfficeId = O.OfficeId
      INNER JOIN [User] U ON C.CreatedByUserId = U.UserId
  WHERE  A.CaseId in(select A.CaseId from Activity where A.CaseId > 1 AND .dbo.DateOnly(AE.ActivityDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate)
  GROUP BY 
        O.OfficeId,
        O.OfficeName,
        AT.Description
```

**Desired GOAL from stored procedure****
I want to return results from this stored procedure where the case count is greater than 0. Currently this stored procedure returns all activities with cases 0 or greater. I am only interested in getting the activities where the cases are greater than 0. In my where clause i am trying to insert another select statement that will filter the results to cases > 0.

Comment: There is possibly an inadvertence in where clause: subquery uses A.CaseID where it should probably use Activity.CaseID, otherwise subquery would be better expressed as where.

Comment: If A.CaseId is uniqueidentifier it could not possibly be greater than 1.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinovć i altered the where clause above and now the error statement is: an aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is in outer reference.

Comment: Why would you try with count? Could you please write down (edit the question so that everybody can see) what you ment with this subquery?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinovć i explained what i wanted out of the subquery above. Thanks for you help currently and in advance.

Comment: I don't see how you could get count(DISTINCT A.CaseId) = 0, because CaseID cannot be null (because of inner join between Activity and Case, and lack of left joins). All you need to do is filter the dates: `WHERE dbo.DateOnly(AE.ActivityDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate`. This will filter out any CaseID not having a record between this dates.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinovć that is correct but i am planning - on combining two stored procedures one that will get cases >=1 and the other is where cases = 0 and i wanted a way that i can filter the results into groups or something because it is giving me a hard time to filter the two groups in a report viewer because i need them both in one stored procedure. Thanks for the help i will try to think of an alternative solution.

Comment: You could get both queries in one if you start with [Case] and left-join other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The error message is telling you**.

One of the comparisons is comparing things from two columns with different types.

Look at the table structures and see which columns you're comparing has uniqueidentifier and which have ints and then look at the sql and see which ones you're comparing.